# Crash using Xcode 6 Beta 4 with AFNetworking on iPhone running iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking-2

I've created a simple project in Xcode 6 Beta 4 using Swift and AFNetworking (2.3.1) (using CocoaPods). I'm using the Master-Detail Application template and I'm using a bridge.h file only containing `#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>`. I've also added the Foundation framework to the project.

When building for an iPhone (works on iPad) using iOS 7.1 (works on iOS 8) I get an error that looks like this:

[image]

If I do it using another template instead of `Master-Detail Application` it works fine.

Comment: I just tried it in a demo project and I'm not getting a crash when I build or run. Is there any particular class in AFNetworking you are trying to use? (I tried AFURLConnectionOperation)

Comment: I tested this in a new project with no added code and I still get the error, you can download my project here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6498500/probablybug.zip

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any symbolic breakpoints set?

Comment: @NikolayKasyanov Yes.